# Is result() a reserved function or keyword in Dart?

Tags: dart

I was just playing around with Dart futures, but encountered an error:

> Uncaught Error: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call$2' on null

then I found out the function 'result' was the cause.
But everything works fine if I use another name for the function.

```
Future<String> result() async {
    var res = await process();
    return 'Your order is: $res';
}

Future<String> process() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 'Water');
}

void main() async {
    print(await result());
}
```

Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: I compiled this code and it works fine. And result is not reserved func or keyword as far as I know.

Comment: I used it on dartpad, and I do get the error. No idea why. It may be a dart2js bug

Comment: I compiled it on dartpad and it throws the error, only if a function is named `result` and is marked as `async` and awaits a future. (Just marking as `async` won't throw any exception)

Comment: Changing the method name, solved the problem. Even I also tried with dartpad, I got error called Script error

Comment: I tried the code in Android Studio and DartPad. In Android studio it works perfectly. But in dartpad I'm getting the exact same error. As @RémiRousselet mentioned, I think it has something to do with dart2js.
Note: There is a built in class called `Result`, defined for the async functionality.

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41204.

Comment: It is a bug reported to sofware developer, nothing can be done here.

Comment: thanks.
i thought so too.maybe a bug in dartpad.